# Error sending wrapper object from Android to Google cloud endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been able to send data from Android to endpoint successfully, but now I am having a problem with trying to send a wrapper object to the endpoint from Android. The error is:

```
actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I didn't use an `@named` annotation, is that the problem? Because all explanations of using a wrapper class show that is should be left out?

I created a custom class, as the wrapper eg:

```
public class ObjectHolder {

    private int b_holder;
    ...etc

    public int getB_holder() {
        return b_holder;
    }

    public void setB_holder(int b_holder) {
        this.b_holder = b_holder;
    }

    ...etc
}
```

Error point!! `objectholder` shows error when trying to rebuild project in android studio. Call endpoint from android:

```
 PObject save = myApiService.getPObject(objectholder).execute();
```

Endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getObject")
public PObject getPObject(ObjectHolder ObjectHolder) {
```

Should the `ObjectHolder` be within the endpoint package or android package, or both? I currently have tried all three options. I get errors for all three.

Answer (score 0):

Not much info to work on, but my guess is you are trying to implement wrapper yourself.

The ObjectHolder wrapper is created for you when you generate the client libs. You should use the provided implementation.